# Nginx Port 443 already in use by it self?

Tags: nginx

I am totally new to Nginx and just playing around with my domain, that I had laying around and not used. Thought I might aswell put it to good use and host API on it. But wanted to learn some Nginx first.

When I check the error log I get the following error:

```
2020/09/07 10:49:54 [emerg] 32432#32432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

When I check "sudo netstat -tulpn":

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32455/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      32455/nginx: master
```

It is nginx it self that is using the port 443?

My config is just overwriting the default nginx conf named "default" in sites-availble and looks like this:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/dotnetdeploy/www_topswagcode_dev.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/dotnetdeploy/www_topswagcode_dev.key;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

After I changed my Config I ran:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

When I type:

```
nginx -T
```

[image: Start]

then there is a lot of types eg:

```
types { ....  }
```

[image: end]

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: What command did you run after changing the config, that resulted on that error of port being in use?

Comment: a simple restart. sudo service nginx restart

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question.

Comment: Added nginx -T to the question. Think it's pretty strange. Trying just to get basic SSL to work with Static page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another copy of nginx already running. You should kill it manually before trying to restart nginx using `systemctl` (stop using `service` as this is deprecated and will be removed eventually).

Comment: Didn't help. Stopped all Nginx running and started it again using systemctl. I tried this aswell: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864

Comment: @Kiksen Eh? That looks completely irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: I )=(%" want to kick my hairy balls so hard. AWS Lightsail has only port 22 and 80 open per default............. I didn't even go there to check............... So all my trying to fix it broke it even more. Start over and check ports. Worked like a charm....

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run 'sudo systemctl disable nginx' so that nginx is not started every time you reboot your hardware, in my case it was Raspberry PI.

I had the same problem and this fixed it.  I had two instances trying to run at the same time utilizing the same 433 port, one from when Raspberry PI booting up and the other when my Docker container trying to start image nginx_app_1 (jc21/nginx-proxy-manager).